# How to render 3d object as 2d with different angles

Tags: java, libgdx

I wanted to make a ship as a 3d object and import it with an atlas file to my 2d libgdx project with different angles like I saw it by another game.

And I was wondering if there is a specific software which should be prefered to make those things.

Where can I create the 3d objects and export them into a big png + atlas file?

[image: Example of the png]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, resource requests (which software to use) are not considered [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Hi Glasow2. As @Pikalek mentioned already, questions of what software to use are considered off-topic. What you are trying to do seems pretty standard that any 3D modelling software should be capable of doing. Maybe you can ask at [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) about more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use my script for converting 3d 3dsmax animations to spritesheets
Link: https://github.com/kalevski/maxSpriter

Comment: Hi kalevski and welcome to GDSE and thanks for contributing! Unfortunately answers that contain links are discouraged. It's better to have all parts of your answer here, with an optional link at the bottom. This is because all questions/answers are meant to be seen by future readers as well, but links could always get broken.